# Understanding ajax POST method, finding url

Tags: ajax

I don't fully understand one thing, how the next code gets the url 
parameter. I would be glad if someone could help.

```
$('.nav-item.home').addClass('active');
$('#searchForm').submit(function(event){

$(this).find('input[name=csrf]').val($('meta[name=csrf]').attr('content'));

$.ajax({
     beforeSend: function(){
        $('.spinner').show();
        $('.innerText').html('');
     },
     type: 'POST',
     data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),
     url: $('#searchForm').data('action'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL parameter for the AJAX call is brought in from the `<form>` tag:

```
url: $('#searchForm').data('action')
```

On the page there is:

```
<form id="searchform" action="urltosomewhere">
```

Is that what you are looking for?